# parseInt and viewflipper layout problems

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, viewflipper, parseint

I have a problem with `parseInt()`, it throws the error: *unable to parse 'null' as integer*, also my `ViewFlipper` isn't working. Here is my activity:

```
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
    import xml.parser.dataset;



   public class XmlParserActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    private final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "WeatherForcaster";
  //  private dataset myDataSet;
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private int temp= 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    //the ViewSwitcher
    private Button btn;
    private ViewFlipper flip;
//  private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            flip=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flip);                              
            //when a view is displayed
            flip.setInAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
            //when a view disappears
            flip.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out); 
      //    String postcode = null;

        //  public String getPostcode {
          //      return postcode;
     //   }

                  //URL newUrl = c;

                //  myweather.setText(c.toString());


            /* Create a new TextView to display the parsingresult later. */
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);





           // run(0);
            //WeatherApplicationActivity postcode = new WeatherApplicationActivity();
            try {

                    /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
                URL url = new URL("http://new.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=gcV3ynNdoV&output=xml&query=G41");

                //String url = new String("http://new.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=gcV3ynNdoV&output=xml&query="+WeatherApplicationActivity.postcode );



                //URL url = new URL(url);
                    //url.toString( );
                   //myString(url.toString() + WeatherApplicationActivity.getString(postcode));
                   // url + WeatherApplicationActivity.getString(postcode);
                    /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

                    /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                    /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
                    handler myHandler = new handler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);

                    /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                    /* Parsing has finished. */

                    /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
                    dataset parsedDataSet =
                                                                    myHandler.getParsedData();

                    /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
                    tv.setText(parsedDataSet.toString());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
                    tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "WeatherQueryError", e);
            }



            temp = Integer.parseInt(xml.parser.dataset.getTemp());


                if(temp <0){
                    //layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    //layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));
                    findViewById(R.id.flip).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                else if(temp > 0 && temp < 9)
                { 
                    //layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    //layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));
                    findViewById(R.id.flip).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else
                {
                    //layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    //layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));
                    findViewById(R.id.flip).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }


      /* Display the TextView. */
    this.setContentView(tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub onClick(View arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        flip.showNext();
         //specify flipping interval             
         //flip.setFlipInterval(1000);           
         //flip.startFlipping();
     }  

    }
```

This is my `dataset`:

```
package xml.parser;



public class dataset {

 static String temp = null;

//  private int extractedInt = 0;


public static String getTemp() {
   return temp;
 }
public void setTemp(String temp) {
   this.temp = temp;
 }
```

This is my handler:

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
 if(this.in_temp){
           String setTemp = new String(ch, start, length);
          // myParsedDataSet.setTempUnit(new String(ch, start, length));
        //   myParsedDataSet.setTemp;
          }
```

For the `dataset` and handler I only pasted the code that involves the `temp` as I know they work when I take out the if statement. However even then my `ViewFlipper` wont work.
This is my `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:text="Flip Example"
/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dip"
    android:text="Flip"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:onClick="ClickHandler"
/>
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/flip">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:text="Item1a"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
    />

</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `Logcat`:

```
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xml.parser/xml.parser.XmlParserActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:356)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at xml.parser.XmlParserActivity.onCreate(XmlParserActivity.java:118)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
04-01 18:02:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(7331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're trying to parse as an `int` a `null` String(you are calling the static method from `dataset` that will return `null`, because the object it returns(`temp`) is set to `null`). You probably want to parse as an `int` the result of the xml parsing, so instead of :

```
temp = Integer.parseInt(xml.parser.dataset.getTemp());
```

use the `parsedDataSet` variable:

```
 temp = Integer.parseInt(parsedDataSet.getTemp());
```

Example:

```
    //....
    dataset parsedDataSet;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "http://new.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=gcV3ynNdoV&output=xml&query=G41");
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        handler myHandler = new handler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        parsedDataSet = myHandler.getParsedData();
        tv.setText(parsedDataSet.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "WeatherQueryError", e);
    }

    temp = Integer.parseInt(parsedDataSet.getTemp());
    //...
```

Also I see other errors in your code:

-In the xml parser, do you actually set the parsed String in the result?

```
// I guess that myParsedDataSet is another dataset object that you return with
// myHandler.getParsedData(), do you set the temp variable in that class?? // myParsedDataSet.setTemp(setTemp);
if(this.in_temp){
           String setTemp = new String(ch, start, length);
          // myParsedDataSet.setTempUnit(new String(ch, start, length));
        //   myParsedDataSet.setTemp;
          }
```

-Also you parse the xml, check the value from `parseInt` and then replace the main layout of the activity with `this.setContentView(tv);`?!

Comment: @user1234167 Well from your code `parsedDataSet` is an instance of `dataset`, you have this line: `dataset parsedDataSet = myHandler.getParsedData();` so calling that method shouldn't be a problem. Declare your `parsedDataSet` before you enter the `try-catch` block and in that block only assign the results to `parsedDataSet`.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would declare that I'm really confused

Comment: I have made the changed am still getting the same error :( as for the replacing the main layout to a textview...cheers for pointing that out I'll change that to setText or something

Comment: @user1234167 Did you also modify the `characters` method from the handler to set the text `myParsedDataSet.setTemp(setTemp);`?

Comment: right i took out that setContentView(tv) u legend. my color is now changed and my flip layout is here :D however...it isnt showing the weather now. Its reading it tho coz the background has changed

Comment: @user1234167 You'll probably want to get one of the `TextView` from the `ViewFlipper`(with `findViewById`) and set on it the text with the weather(which you parsed).

Comment: cheers buddy I was overriding it with this line: TextView tv = new TextView(this);

Comment: Thanks so much for your help you both are lifesavers :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if your `parseddatadset` is null and if yes add "0" in the from of String before pasiing it as an integer.

Can be implemented as follows -

```
String checknull=parseddataset.toString();
if(checknull.length()==0)
  checknull += "0";
```

I would recommend the use of an `boolean` variable and if it results in false(!=0) then only parse it otherwise you know that it parseddataset is empty.In your case where you are using `xml.parser.dataset.getTemp()` check if its length is 0 and parse if false.

Comment: infact I have just changed this:static String temp = "0"; and it is now coming up as 0 degrees

Comment: Obviously it will show 0 now as you made temp static and equal to '0' just make this change `String temp=0` and if it will read anything from the parser then `0` will get replaced by the `parsed value` otherwise it will be `0` only. So if you still get `0` that means the file isn't getting parsed. And sorry didnt notice the declaration of temp earlier otherwise would have given the answer to initialize the String temp by 0. Anyways,this `String temp=0` should fix the problem. :D

Comment: I have now got it working and I still have it declared as static string however...its reading my data as the color has changed according to the temp. and my layout has now appeared. The problem now is my data has disappeared